# Adding values from a text file into a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to add values from a text file with lots of data into a HashMap. This is a tiny sample from the content of the text file:

**Outlook Temperature Humidity Windy GoOutside**
 sunny...........hot..............high..........false.....No
 overcast........hot...............high.........false......Yes

the "....." are spaces in the text file.

I have stored the heading of each column in an array and I want them to be the keys in my HashMap, so for example

```
   array[0] == "outlook"
```

I have the following HashMap

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Assuming that the program is reading the file correctly, how can I make sure that I am inserting each value into the correct key?

Thank you for your time

Comment: How are you planning on doing this with a `<String, String>` hashmap? You might want to end up using `<String, String[]>` or maybe even create a Weather object.

Comment: are you going to have a different hash map for each row of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HashMap inbuit function put to insert keys into the HashMap and use get function to get the value of any particular key inserted into the HashMap.

```
        HashMap<String,String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
        //write code for taking input from file into string arrays
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                map.put(weather[i], condition[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

Here i is number of rows of input for each weather and j is for the following string value i.e, temperature, humidity, windy and go outside.